# Exception to be thrown when file doesn't have required permissions

Tags: python, exception

I have a `try except` block where I am checking the file permissions and my `except` block should return the appropriate error message when the file permissions are too open.

```
if oct(os.stat(self.file_path).st_mode & 0o700):
    try:
        # do something with file path
    except MyError as err:
        return {'1': 'Permissions on the .bsm file is too opened'}
```

I tried searching for an `IOError` but I didn't find it quite relevant for my use-case and the `MyError` that I have defined throws `unresolved reference` error.

What is the more appropriate exception to define here?
My exception should return me a dictionary with `1` as the `key` and error message as `value`.

Comment: Wouldn't that be `except PermissionError as e: print (e)`?

Comment: You haven't defined `MyError`. Also, exceptions don't return anything, although a `return` statement can be executed in an `except` block.

Comment: @poobear, were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

It should be `PermissionError` in your exception:

```
   if oct(os.stat(self.file_path).st_mode & 0o700):
        try:
        # do something with file path
        except PermissionError as err:
            return {'1': str(err)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom exception class extending the Base `Exception` class. 
Maybe something like this.

```
class MyError(Exception):
    """
    A common exception class
    """
    message = 'Some default message'

    def __init__(self, message=None):
        self.message = message or self.message
        super(MyError, self).__init__(self.message)

def is_file_readable():
    return False

try:
    if not is_file_readable():
        raise MyError(message={'cause': 'File not readable'})

except MyError as e:
    print(e.message)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write this function like this
**Solution 1:**

```
if oct(os.stat(self.file_path).st_mode & 0o700):
  try:
    # do something with file path
  except Exception as err:
    print(err) #if you want to see the error message
    return {'1': 'Permissions on the .bsm file is too opened'}
```

**Solution 2:**
If you also want to know the file open exception . then try this:

```
try:
  fileopen = oct(os.stat(self.file_path).st_mode & 0o700)
  if fileopen:
    try:
      # do something with file path
    except Exception as err:
      print(err) #if you want to see the error message
      return {'1': 'Permissions on the .bsm file is too opened'}

except Exception as e:
  print("File open error",e)
```